# What does it mean that " normalize a vector by the maximal value of it"?

Tags: matlab, normalization

Suppose there is a vector H , dose " normalize a vector by the maximal value of it" mean H/max(H)? Every element in H divided by maximal of H?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You divide each element of the vector by the vector's maximum value, so that every value falls in the range `[0, 1]` or `[-1, 1]` if negative values are present. It's commonly used in statistics-related stuff.

You are correct, it's `H / max(H)` and if you are dealing with more than 1 dimensions (like a 2D array), it's
`H / max(H(:))`

edit: as MHH pointed out in the comments, if any of your values is negative, you divide by `max(abs(H))`.

Comment: this is assuming all values are positive. If the vector has negative values usually you'd do H/max(abs(H))

Comment: Just be careful if the vector is all zeros or happens to contain `Inf` or `NaN`.

Comment: To avoid 0/0 (if entire vector is zero), it is better to do `(H/(max(abs(H))+eps))`.

Comment: @ParagSChandakkar: that would work, but I don't think that it necessary to introduce small numerical deviations in certain situations just to be able to put everything on one line of code. I think a better approach is: `v=H/max(abs(H(:)));` `v(isnan(v))=0;`. You may still need a case if the vector contains `Inf` -and figure out how you want to normalize in that case depending on what the infinities represent.